# Run code after all parent/child databindings are done loading

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, data-binding

I have a form with 3 `DataGridView` controls each with a `BindingSource` bound to a DataSet table linked to an Access database. One of the `BindingSource` controls is a parent control, and the other two are linked using a relationship (in the Access database and the VS DataSet) to the parent control. The initial setup was done with some simple drag/drops to the form, and that all works fine. When I change the current record for the parent grid control, the other two change as well.

I would like to run code that used the information in all 3 tables/grids, so I need to be able to detect when all the tables are done changing when the current record of the parent `BindingSource` changes.

I have tried using the `_CurrentChanged` event of the parent `BindingSource`, and that fires as expected, but the child `BindingSource` controls are still populated with the previous record's data. The `_CurrentChanged` event for the child `BindingSource` controls fire too, but I would prefer not to depend on those if I didn't have to.

Some research shows that maybe I would need to use a `BindingManagerBase` concept that I know nothing about, but I am not sure about that. Maybe there is a way to force the child `BindingSource` controls to load the new child data so I can process the results in the parent `_CurrentChanged` event?

Please at least just give me some hints? I am not asking for completed code, just some direction while I learn some basic concepts that I have yet to learn.

If this has been asked somewhere, a link to that would be great too, but I was not able to find anything on my own, probably because I am not using the correct terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there's no need or point to using the `BindingManagerBase` class. It used to be that you had to use the `BindingContext` property of a control to get a `CurrencyManager` object to manage certain aspects of data-binding. `CurrencyManager` inherits `BindingManagerBase`. The `BindingSource` class exists so that you don't have to do that and it wraps up some other binding functionality as well.

As for the issue, there's no simple way to do just that. You need to twiddle a little bit. You need to use the fact that, when you select a new parent record, a child `BindingSource` will raise its `ListChanged` event with a `ListChangedType` of `Reset`. You have two child `BindingSources` so you need to wait until both have raised that event. Matters are complicated by the fact that those events will also be raised while the binding is being set up, so you need to ignore those events. Something like this should do the trick:

```
Private isLoaded As Boolean = False
Private childrenResetCount As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Set up binding here.

    isLoaded = True
End Sub

Private Sub BindingSources_ListChanged(sender As Object, e As ListChangedEventArgs) Handles BindingSource1.ListChanged,
                                                                                            BindingSource2.ListChanged
    If isLoaded AndAlso e.ListChangedType = ListChangedType.Reset Then
        childrenResetCount += 1

        If childrenResetCount = 2 Then
            'Use child data here.

            childrenResetCount = 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I see the concept. I kinda figured it would need to be something along those lines, but I had not considered a simple counter. I'll give it a shot. Thanks so much. It seems many of the things I expect to be able to do "aren't that simple"... But this isn't all that complex.